# Open Related List custom button in new window or close VisualForce page after export

Tags: visualforce

I have a standard page layout for Account.
On that page layout I added a related list of my custom object.
I want to have an 'export' button to export that related list.
I added a VF custom controller that creates the CSV as a string and then I created a VF page as a List Button on my custom object.
This works but unfortunately `open in New window` is not available for `List Button` in SF, so the current behaviour is that the user clicks my button they get the csv download but they are staring on the weird white screen.

What can I do to either open my VF page in a new tab or close it/go back after export?